# CSS transition repeat?

Tags: css, css-transitions

I'm designing a UI where you can select certain objects.  When you do, an information pane slides out.  Everything works great, except if you switch between items I want the animation to run again.

Here is the full codepen: http://codepen.io/ScottBeeson/pen/JGyDa

Here is the relevant CSS:

```
#info.show {
    transition-property: all;
    transition-duration: .5s;
    transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0, 1, 0.5, 1);
}
```

Here is the relevant JS:

```
$('#items div').on('click', function() {
  $('#info').removeClass('show').addClass('show').html('Box ' + $(this).html() + ' is selected')
})
```

Comment: if you were using animation it would be straightforward. Take a look here: http://www.kirupa.com/html5/looping_a_css_transition.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like removing the class does not result in hiding the div first as you expected. You can try using `setTimeout` to add the class outside the `onclick` event handler (after removing the class):

```
$('#items div').on('click', function() {
  $('#info').removeClass('show');
  setTimeout(function(){
               $('#info').addClass('show')
                         .html('Box ' + $(this).html() + ' is selected')
            }.bind(this),1);
})
```

### [Updated demo.](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/hAHdq)

The `bind` method may not be supported by some old browsers, try using `$.proxy` method of jQuery instead ***[Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/IhpAg)***.

Comment: I like this method but for some reason it's not working in my local code.  I'll keep playing with it.

Comment: @ScottBeeson I can't access pastebin, looks like it limits access from my country, also on what browser you tried it?

Comment: Chrome.  Your demo works fine on CodePen, but my local code is a bit different.  Let me put it somewhere else.

Comment: @ScottBeeson I've tested that link, it works fine on my side.

Comment: @ScottBeeson it's hard to say what's wrong here. I doubt that the code between `removeClass` and `addClass` has something wrong, so the code for adding class is not run, have you tried viewing the console for any possible error?

Answer (score 0):

**[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/rewobo/1/edit)**

```
<div id="info">Box ? is selected</div>

<div id="items">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
</div>
```

```
#items div {
  position: relative;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  margin: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
}
#info {
  position:fixed;
  z-index:2;
  width:100%;
  top:-50px;
  left:0;
  background:gold;
  padding:5px 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  color: blue;
}
```

```
var $info = $('#info'), // Cache your elements you plan to reuse over and over.
    infoOrgTop = parseInt( $info.css('top'), 10 ), // Get org top position
    infoTimeout = null; // Timeout to hide Info bar

function showinfo() {

  clearTimeout(infoTimeout); // Don't hide if we clicked another item

  $info.text( "Box "+ $(this).text() +" is selected" );
  $info.stop(0,1).animate({top: 0}, 400);
  infoTimeout = setTimeout(function(){
    $info.animate({top: infoOrgTop}); 
  }, 2000); // hide annoying gold bar after 2s

}

$('#items div').on('click', showinfo);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code -

CSS -

```
#info {  
   position: absolute; 
   left: 75px; top: 0px;  
   width: 200px;  
   overflow: hidden;  
   text-align: center;  
   padding: 0px;  
   background-color: yellow;  
   color: blue;  
  display:none;
}
```

JQUERY -

```
$('#items div').on('click', function() {  
   $('#info').hide();  
   $('#info').slideDown(500).html('Box ' + $(this).html() + ' is selected')
});
```